# Curious about WinForm Control Thread Safety After Adding a Control on a Seperate Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I have a FileSystemWatcher set to pick up an picture that will be dropped in a particular directory.  The way I was handling it was to add a PictureBox in code that is docked inside of a panel.  I ran it, it blew up, and I realized that I was not handling the interaction with the controls on the main thread correctly.  Here is the code:

```
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pnlCapturePicture.Controls.Add(pb);
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.ImageLocation = photopath;
```

Now I understand how to make [Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls][1] but I am curious if I **just** make the Panel Add thread safe am I really accomplishing anything?

Say if I did this:

```
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        AddControlThreadSafe(pb);
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.ImageLocation = photopath;
```

Is interacting with the PictureBox control after it is added to the panel really thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not work. *All* GUI code must be done on the appropriate user interface thread. The thread context is not checked all the time, so it's possible to write something like that which will work now but fail on a future .NET framework update.

In your case `FileSystemWatcher` understands the `ISynchronizeInvoke` pattern, so just set its `SynchronizingObject` property to the form it works with. Note that if you put a `FileSystemWatcher` on a form using the designer, this property is set automatically.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you answered the question that I didn't even ask but should have!

Answer (score 2):

No that will not work. Well, at least it will not work consistently. It might work for awhile, but eventually it will fail unpreditably and spectaculary.  The general rule is that you cannot do anything to a `Form` or `Control` on any other thread than the one it was created on. In other words, they have thread affinity.  What you really need to do is have the main UI thread create and modify the `PictureBox` by marshaling a message into it. This can be done by taking advantage of the `ISynchronizeInvoke` methods. All forms and controls implement this interface.

```
public void ThreadMethod()
{
  pnlCapturePicture.Invoke((Action)(() =>
  {
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); 
    pnlCapturePicture.Controls.Add(pb); 
    pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
    pb.ImageLocation = photopath; 
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Control::CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to true in the beginning of the program. In this case, every cross-thread operation with Windows Forms immediately crashes the program. This is better than default undefined behavior, when CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx

Comment: The default on my controls appears to be True.